# webbased employee work schedule

Tags: untagged

I'm looking for a solution to organize the work shifts of a department like this:

- 15 employees with each has a different number of hours to work
- Monday-Friday, 6:00-22:00
- always one or more employees on shift
- overlapping shifts
- self-organization: employees plan their shifts on their own

must have:

- runs on linux
- open source
- webinterface
- ability to change someone else's shifts

nice to have:

- user authentication against radius, samba or imap
- versioning (see who changed something)
- exporting to something like csv or ics
- tracking of overtime and vacation

I guess that I am not the first to set up something like this and I'd be really thankful for a recommendation.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the [updated FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq). They're generally off topic StackExchange wide as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These guys here seem to have a lot of what you're after: http://www.livetecs.com/. It's not free though, but then you didn't stipulate that in your question so I guess it should be OK. It's ASP though.

Otherwise you might have to delve into Project Management software, but use it for shifts instead of projects. Something like [Task Juggler](http://www.taskjuggler.org/) comes to mind, but it could be a bit of a stretch...

Comment: I had the same though about project management software. Another one to look at is http://openproj.org/openproj